# Fetch a column according to List in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

This is what my dataframe looks like, How can i fetch column b of the dataframe where `a=[98,43,23,2,5]` such that it returns `[12,39,23,32,78]`

```
a   b   c
2   32  34
5   78  23
98  12  11
23  23  66
43  39  43
```

I want to write a method that takes in a list(to compare with column a), and returns a list back(corresponding values of b) from the dataframe.

```
def get_reordered_b_according_to_a(a_list):
    #code 
    return reordered_list_b
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), if some value ixist in list and not in column `a` is returned NaNs:

```
a=[98,43,23,2,5]

def get_reordered_b_according_to_a(a_list):
    return df.set_index('a').b.reindex(a_list).tolist()
print (get_reordered_b_according_to_a(a))
[12, 39, 23, 32, 78]
```

---

```
a=[43,23,2,5,7]
def get_reordered_b_according_to_a(a_list):
    return df.set_index('a').b.reindex(a_list).tolist()
print (get_reordered_b_according_to_a(a))
[39.0, 23.0, 32.0, 78.0, nan]
```